# draw rect when touch began Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want a rect to be drawn when I touch the screen. The rect is drawn if I do it directly without having to touch the screen. But when I do it when the screen is touches it isn't drawn. This is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
touchBegan = YES;

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];


}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (touchBegan)
{
    CGRect jrect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, jrect);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

}
```

Why isn't it drawn?

Comment: A view won't trigger `drawRect:` itself unless you tell it to do so explicitly. `[self setNeedsDisplay];` should be moved to the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. (It would cause infinite recursion in the other method, anyway.)

Comment: That's what it is. Why should `drawRect` be invoked Try moving that `setNeedsDisplay` to `touchesBegan:` And never call `setNeedsDisplay` from within `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

You must call drawrect:(Cgrect)rect for drawing your rect ex:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

[self drawrect:(Cgrect)rect];


}
```